# python re.compile strings with vars and numbers

Tags: python, regex, nlp

Hi I want to get a match for the following:

`test = re.compile(r' [0-12](am|pm) [1-1000] days from (yesterday|today|tomorrow)')`

with this match:

`print test.match(" 3pm 2 days from today")`

It returns none, what am i doing wrong? I am just getting into regex and reading the docs I thought this should work! ANY HELP APPRECIATED
chrism

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I am asking a new question about the design of a sytem using similar process to above in NLP [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789126/pyton-re-match-findall-or-search-and-then-nlp-what-to-do-with-it)

Comment: The first numerical range is not expressed correctly

Comment: any examples of how this could work, its late at night here in ireland and i'm struggling :) hold on i copied wrong code in my example editing now

Comment: you can't specify number ranges that way. `[0-12]` matches 0,1, or 2. not a number between 0 and 12. `0-1` is a character range that includes 0 and 1, the 2 is just a 2...it matches ANY of the characters within [].

Comment: Instead of: `[0-12]` which says: _"match one character in the range from '0' to '1', or a `2`"_, and: `[1-1000]` which says: _"match one character in the range from '1' to '1', or a '0' or a '0' or a '0'"_ (the `[...]` expression is a _character class_), use `\d+` instead which says: _"match one or more digits"_. Regexes are _fun!_ But I would strongly recommend spending an hour or two studying the basics. There is an excellent online tutorial at: [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). The time you spend there will pay for itself many times over. Happy regexing!

Comment: Well I did fall asleep as it was 2am GMT, wow! thank you people for your generous contribution, I will try out the various proposals.

Comment: I appreciate your time guys, but, I found that stating that "you can't specify number ranges that way. [0-12] matches 0,1, or 2. not a number between 0 and 12" was a confusing comment,also suggesting to use \d+ to match a time does not work(14pm?). Clearly [1-9] does match the range 1-9. What I didn't know was that to match my required range of numbers for a given time in 12 hour (or any range including numbers above 9), one should use r' ([1-9]|1[012])' or similar which will match times from 1-12 or other similar patterns, i am starting to have "fun" now:).

Comment: @Murray3 Why do you want to exclude "0 days" ?

Comment: 0 days would not usually be referred to in normal speach or text, one would type the time in hours and minutes for a time period of less than a day, but i guess you are thinking of parsing sentence structure or jisting, which would exclude this with my regex.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my hat in the ring. Careful study of this regex will teach a few lessons:

```py
import re
reobj = re.compile(
    r"""# Loosely match a date/time reference
    ^                    # Anchor to start of string.
    \s*                  # Optional leading whitespace.
    (?P<time>            # $time: military or AM/PM time.
      (?:                # Group for military hours options.
        [2][0-3]         # Hour is either 20, 21, 22, 23,
      | [01]?[0-9]       # or 0-9, 00-09 or 10-19
      )                  # End group of military hours options.
      (?:                # Group for optional minutes.
        :                # Hours and minutes separated by ":"
        [0-5][0-9]       # 00-59 minutes
      )?                 # Military minutes are optional.
    |                    # or time is given in AM/PM format.
      (?:1[0-2]|0?[1-9]) # 1-12 or 01-12 AM/PM options (hour)
      (?::[0-5][0-9])?   # Optional minutes for AM/PM time.
      \s*                # Optional whitespace before AM/PM.
      [ap]m              # Required AM or PM (case insensitive)
    )                    # End group of time options.
    \s+                  # Required whitespace.
    (?P<offset> \d+ )    # $offset: count of time increments.
    \s+                  # Required whitespace.
    (?P<units>           # $units: units of time increment.
      (?:sec(?:ond)?|min(ute)?|hour|day|week|month|year|decade|century)
      s?                 # Time units may have optional plural "s".
    )                    # End $units: units of time increment.
    \s+                  # Required whitespace.
    (?P<dir>from|before|after|since) # #dir: Time offset direction.
    \s+                  # Required whitespace.
    (?P<base>yesterday|today|tomorrow|(?:right )?now)
    \s*                  # Optional whitespace before end.
    $                    # Anchor to end of string.""", 
    re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE)
match = reobj.match(' 3 pm 2 days from today')
if match:
    print('Time:       %s' % (match.group('time')))
    print('Offset:     %s' % (match.group('offset')))
    print('Units:      %s' % (match.group('units')))
    print('Direction:  %s' % (match.group('dir')))
    print('Base time:  %s' % (match.group('base')))
else:
    print("No match.")
```

**Output:**

```
r"""
Time:       3 pm
Offset:     2
Units:      days
Direction:  from
Base time:  today
"""
```

This regex illustrates a few lessons to be learned:

- Regular expressions are very powerful (and useful)!
- This regex does validate the numbers, but as you can see, doing so is cumbersome and difficult (and thus, not recommended - I'm showing it here to demonstrate why not to do it this way). It is much easier to simply capture the numbers with a regex then validate the ranges using procedural code.
- Named capture groups ease the pain of plucking multiple data sub-strings from larger text.
- Always write regexes using free-spacing, verbose mode with proper indentation of groups and lots of descriptive comments. This helps while writing the regex and later during maintenance.

Modern regular expressions comprise a rich and powerful language. Once you [learn the syntax](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) and develop a habit of writing verbose, properly indented, well-commented code, then even complex regexes such as the one above are easy to write, easy to read and are easy to maintain. It is unfortunate that they have acquired a reputation for being difficult, unwieldy and error-prone (and thus not recommendable for complex tasks).

Happy regexing!

Comment: @ridgerunner Wow ! Such a work and good reflections. +1 . You seem to be fond of regexes. I am 99 % in agreement with your ideas. The 1 % different is that I prefer to use the possibility to write several strings on several lines between parentheses -> they will be automatically concatenated + the fact that it's even possible to put # a commentary before the end of each line -> the RE works the same (I edited my answer to show that) ! There are two reasons:

Comment: I am a little confused by the fact that the boundaries of the elements of a verbose RE are optically (is it right english ??) vague on each line. With my manner to write, I have the commentary and the RE element of different colors. / And also, since blanks are not taken in account in a verbose RE, it happened one time that it caused me a problem. - By the way, I don't find that the expressions to validate the numbers are cumbersome.

Comment: @eyquem: Thanks, yes I like regex very much. I don't understand your question about the _boundaries of the elements_ - can you explain your question in more detail?

Comment: @ridgerunner For me a RE (a string that is submitted to a compilation to give a compiled regex object) is composed of elemental REs. ``"(?>= )"`` is an elemental RE, ``"(?:2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9])"`` is an elemental RE composed of elemental REs ``"[2][0-3]"`` and ``"[01]?[0-9]"`` , composed of sub-elemental REs ``"2"`` , ``"[0-3]"`` , ``"[01]"`` , ``"[0-9]"`` .... In your RE, my mind hesitates to know where begins the elemental RE ``[2][0-3]`` : do the blanks before are in the elem RE ? , where does it stop after [2][0-3] ? , the blank between [2][0-3] and the character # troubles me slightly, etc.

Comment: @ridgerunner Each time I see a verbose RE, I must do an effort to recall the fact that « Whitespace within the pattern is ignored, except when ... etc » and I don't perceive immediately the boundaries (limits, I should have written) between a character belonging to an elemetal RE and a blank outside of it. That's why I prefer to write a global RE by stacking the elemental REs in lines, each one well delimited between limiting quotes ``"..."`` . That's subjective.

Comment: @ridgerunner Moreover, if I need to represent a whitespace in a verbose RE, I must recall that « Whitespace within the pattern is ignored, except when in a character class or preceded by an unescaped backslash » and it annoys me.

Comment: @ridgerunner By the way, I you define the group names as being the strings that will be printed in the output displayed, you can simplify the printing instruction: ``(?P<Time>`` , ``(?P<Offset> \d+ )`` , ``(?P<Units>`` , ``(?P<Direction>from|`` , ``(?P<Base_time>yester`` in the RE. Then ``grnames = ('Time','Offset','Units','Direction','Base_time')`` is used to executes ``print '\n'.join('%-12s:%s' % (x.replace('_','') ,match.group(x)) for x in grnames)`` . A group name must be a valid Pythonic identifier, without blank, hence the needed **replace('_','')**

Comment: Thankyou for this, I was trying to write code that would capture part of sentence "types" and if they match a criteria, start a specific python script that deals with the "type." example for this regex was to use pyparsing datetime conversion script that returned a datetime and then did a db insert into my/users diary if other parts of the sentence matched another "type" ie. appointments etc.

Comment: Great regex :) although of course the plural of "century" is "centuries", so your regex will fail in this extremely common case...

Answer (score 2):

what about

```
test = re.compile(r' ([0-9]|1[012])(am|pm) \d+ days from (yesterday|today|tomorrow)')
```

the hours part should match 0, 1, ..., 9 or 10, 11, 12
but not 13, 14, ..., 19.

you can limit days part in similar way for 1, ..., 1000, i.e. (1000|\d{1,3}).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import re

test = re.compile('^\s[0-1]?[0-9]{1}pm \d+ days from (today|yesterday|tomorrow)$')

print test.match(" 12pm 2 days from today")
```

The problem that you're having is that you can't specify multiple digit numeric ranges in regex (afaik), so you have to treat them as individual characters.

**[Sample here](http://codepad.org/qMQLn3Ud)**

Comment: Thank you very much, i ammended to: test = re.compile(r' ([1-9]|1[012])(am|pm) \d+ days from (yesterday|today|tomorrow)') in order to only match times from 1-12am i.e. not 0pm

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
test = re.compile(' \d+(am|pm) \d+ days from (yesterday|today|tomorrow)')
```

Comment: @Damian: yes. IMHO, regex should not be used for validation but should be used only to make sure that text is structured properly. OTOH, almost all the answers here will work for invalid time ranges (e.g. " 19pm 2 days from today")

Comment: cool, just wasn't sure whether or not you were aware. funny, the varying opinions you can find here on topics such as what regex should and shouldn't be used for :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract the parts of the match individually, you can label the groups with `(?P<name>[match])`.  For example:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(
    r'\s*(?P<time>1?[0-9])(?P<ampm>am|pm)\s+'
    r'(?P<days>[1-9]\d*)\s+days\s+from\s+'
    r'(?P<when>yesterday|today|tomorrow)\s*')

for time in range(0, 13):
    for ampm in ('am', 'pm'):
        for days in range(1, 1000):
            for when in ('yesterday', 'today', 'tomorrow'):
                text = ' %d%s %d days from %s ' % (time, ampm, days, when)
                match = pattern.match(text)
                assert match is not None
                keys = sorted(match.groupdict().keys())
                assert keys == ['ampm', 'days', 'time', 'when']

text = ' 3pm 2 days from today '
print pattern.match(text).groupdict()
```

Output:

```
{'time': '3', 'when': 'today', 'days': '2', 'ampm': 'pm'}
```

Comment: (imho) seems to be a little over-engineered for the specified requirements

Comment: The only difference is I'm using named groups. I suggested this since it isn't much more work, and he may use it for more complex patterns in the future (e.g. the `nlp` tag was given, and I've personally used this same pattern to more easily manage highly-complex regexp-based tokenizers).

Comment: `re.VERBOSE` and one capture group per line might be more readable. The regex is too permissive e.g., `'11119am 0 days from today'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
test = re.compile(' 1?\d[ap]m \d{1,3} days? from (?:yesterday|today|tomorrow)')
```

### EDIT

Having read the discussion between Rumple Stiltskin and Demian Brecht, I noticed that my above proposition is poor because it detects a certain structure of string, but it doesn't validate precisely it is a good "time-pattern" string, because it can detect " 18pm 2 days from today" for exemple.

So I propose now a pattern that allows to detect precisely a string verifying your requirement and that points out every string having the same structure as a valid one but not with the required values of a valid good "time-pattern" string:

```
import re

regx = re.compile("(?<= )"  # better than a blank as first character
                  ""
                  "(?:(1[012]|\d)([ap]m) (?!0 )(\d{1,3}|1000)"
                  "|"
                  "(\d+)([ap]m) (\d+))"
                  ""
                  " days? from (yesterday|today|tomorrow)") # shared part




for ch in (" 12pm 2 days from today",
           " 4pm 1 day from today",
           " 12pm 0 days from today",
           " 12pm 1001 days from today",
           " 18pm 2 days from today",
           " 1212pm 2 days from today",
           " 12pm five days from today"):

    print ch
    mat = regx.search(ch)
    if mat:
        if mat.group(1):
            print mat.group(1,2,3,7),'\n# time-pattern-VALIDATED string #'
        else:
            print mat.group(4,5,6,7),'\n* SIMILI-time-pattern STRUCTURED string*'
    else:
        print '- NO STRUCTURED STRING in the text -'
    print
```

result

```
 12pm 2 days from today
('12', 'pm', '2', 'today') 
# time-pattern-VALIDATED string #

 4pm 1 day from today
('4', 'pm', '1', 'today') 
# time-pattern-VALIDATED string #

 12pm 0 days from today
('12', 'pm', '0', 'today') 
* SIMILI-time-pattern STRUCTURED string*

 12pm 1001 days from today
('12', 'pm', '1001', 'today') 
* SIMILI-time-pattern STRUCTURED string*

 18pm 2 days from today
('18', 'pm', '2', 'today') 
* SIMILI-time-pattern STRUCTURED string*

 1212pm 2 days from today
('1212', 'pm', '2', 'today') 
* SIMILI-time-pattern STRUCTURED string*

 12pm five days from today
- NO STRUCTURED STRING in the text -
```

If you need only a regex that detects a time-pattern validated string, you use only

```
regx = re.compile("(?<= )(1[012]|\d)([ap]m) (?!0 )(\d{1,3}|1000) days?"
                  " from (yesterday|today|tomorrow)")
```

Comment: it is interesting the way you look for patterns, i like this approach, refer to my comments above and part 2 of question for my reasoning

Answer (score 0):

It is easier (and more readable) to check integer ranges after the match:

```
m = re.match(r' (\d+)(?:pm|am) (\d+) days from (yesterday|today|tomorrow)',
             " 3pm 2 days from today")
assert m and int(m.group(1)) <= 12 and 1 <= int(m.group(2)) <= 1000
```

Or you could use an existing library e.g., [`pip install parsedatetime`](https://code.google.com/p/parsedatetime/):

```
import parsedatetime.parsedatetime as pdt

cal = pdt.Calendar()
print cal.parse("3pm 2 days from today")
```

#### Output

```
((2011, 4, 26, 15, 0, 0, 1, 116, -1), 3)
```

Comment: Really think it's more readable? Deciphering the regex and then the assertions seems to require more thought than just the expression.. Although my argument is entirely subjective :)

Comment: @Demian Brecht: It is more readable to write an *invalid* regular expression that either too strict or too permissive such as the regex from your answer.

Comment: f.: sure, easy to write incorrect regex, but if you have specific requirements, then you should be able to formulate one to match them and not have to introduce further logic to ensure your expression's validity. again, just my humble opinion :)